# When $u \in L^q$ then $\partial u / \partial x_i \in W^{-1,q}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipshitz domain, $u \in L^q(\Omega)$.

I am reading some article that assume as clear that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \in W^{-1,q}(\Omega).$$

Is that true?

I can show that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \in W^{-1,q'}(\Omega)$ since for $\phi \in W^{1,q'}(\Omega)$ i have by Green's formula

$$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \phi\, dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} u \phi \nu_i \, dS - \int_\Omega u \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} \, dx$$

and since both integrals on the right hand side make sense I can identify $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$ with that particular linear functional and thus $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \in W^{-1,q'}(\Omega)$. But is also $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \in W^{-1,q}(\Omega)$?

Comment: The dual of $W^{1,q'}_0$ is $W^{-1,q}$. So your Green's formula proves the result (easier even: with $0$ b.c. for $\phi$ so that the boundary term vanishes) .

Comment: It expains it, I had not known the correct notation, thank you.